# How to go to next page in a website and continue scrolling and so on while web scrolling in selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to extract all reviews of an app from a website but the automatic scroller stops at show page button which need to be clicked and scrolled through next page and so on till the end. What do i need to add to click and scroll again?

I am using selenium to do it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import datetime

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
url="https://www.g2.com/products/sap-concur/reviews?focus_review=2070722&product_id=sap-concur"

browser.maximize_window()
browser.get(url)
html = browser.page_source.encode('utf-8').strip()
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
reviews = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"x-review slat slat--review"})
for tag in reviews:
    print(str(tag))
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pjax-container"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[6]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
reviews2 = soup.find_all('div', {"class":"x-review slat slat--review"})
for tag in reviews2:
    print(str(tag))
```

Comment: Which app are you trying?can you share the url?